# How to implement Circuit breaker in spring framework 6 declarative clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In a spring boot project, I would like to implement `CicrcuitBreaker` when connecting to 3rd party services using spring frameworks new declarative client

What I have done till now

1. Added below dependency in POM.xml as declarative client uses webclient underneath

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2. Added below properties in application.properties

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.slidingWindowSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.eventConsumerBufferSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.recordExceptions[0]=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.recordExceptions[1]=java.net.ConnectException
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.recordExceptions[2]=java.io.IOException

resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.timeoutDuration=5s
resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.cancelRunningFuture=true

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
```

3. Created a Bean of type `ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory` as below.

```java
    @Bean
    Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory ->
                factory.configureDefault(
                        id ->
                                new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                                        .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
                                        .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.ofDefaults())
                                        .build());
    }
```

4. Added `CircuitBreaker` to the `HttpServiceProxyFactory` Bean as below

```java
    @Bean
    public HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory(
            WebClient.Builder builder,
            ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker =
                resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory
                        .getCircuitBreakerRegistry()
                        .circuitBreaker("default");

        WebClient webClient =
                builder.baseUrl(applicationProperties.getInventoryServiceUrl())
                        .filter(
                                (request, next) ->
                                        next.exchange(request)
                                                .transform(
                                                        CircuitBreakerOperator.of(circuitBreaker)))
                        .defaultHeaders(
                                httpHeaders -> {
                                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                                    httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                                })
                        .build();
        return HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient)).build();
    }
```

When 3rd party service is down it is not giving any fallback response, how to fix this.

Another approach tried

Annotating the method with @CircuitBreaker and creating fallback method, still it is giving me exception.

```java
    @CircuitBreaker(
        name = "getInventoryByProductCode",
        fallbackMethod = "getInventoryByProductCodeFallBack")
    private InventoryDto getInventoryByProductCode(String code) {
        return inventoryServiceProxy.getInventoryByProductCode(code);
    }

    private InventoryDto getInventoryByProductCodeFallBack(String code, Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occurred while fetching product details", e);
        return new InventoryDto(code, 0);
    }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: This has not been implemented yet

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb, any near plans to implement it??

Comment: Yes, it is being planned

Comment: Hi @spencergibb, with new RestClient Introduced in spring boot 3.2.0. Will we have support?

Comment: Not explicitly. We don't have it for `WebClient` or `RestTemplate`. You need to use the circuit breaker explicitly. See this for an example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/blob/dbdb0d35bdb9adb6fbc5658e62728c091d7febcb/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/circuitbreaker/resilience4j/Resilience4JCircuitBreakerIntegrationTest.java#L231C1-L256